# Dimension of a infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a simple multiple choice I've been trying to understand here for a while now.

> Suppose that $F$ is spanned by the functions $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$. What can we conclude about $\text{dim}(V)$?

> a) $\text{dim}(V)=4$

> b) $\text{dim}(V)\geq 4$, but we know nothing else

> c) $\text{dim}(V)\leq 4$, but we know nothing else

> d) We can conclude nothing about $\text{dim}(V)$

> e) None of the above

NORMALLY I would say that the answer is $b)$ but that only holds for a finite dimensional vector space. I'm not sure if I can assume that $b$ is true if $F$ is infinite dimensional.

Can someone guide me on this? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is c). There is no infinite dimensional space in this question.

Comment: Okay so I need to ask. Why? I thought since F could be anything, it's infinite dimensional.

Also why is it c? For that to happen, don't the vectors have to all be linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are linearly independent, then $\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$ is a basis of $F$, hence $\dim (V)=4.$

If $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ are linearly dependent, then $ \dim(V) \le 3.$

The answer is c).

Comment: How do you know the vectors are linearly dependent? Is it because they span $F$ so it's possible to express one or more vectors as a linear combination of each other and hence the dimension can be at most $3$?